# VueJS: changing number of paginate values?

Tags: pagination, vue.js

My problem is: I'm trying to do a pagination function to my datatable, it works fine but when I change the limit of items in my table, the total of pages doesn't update. How can I proceed? I have this filter:

```
    filters: {
        paginate: function(list) {
            this.resultCount = this.movimientos.length;
            if (this.currentPage >= this.totalPages) {
              this.currentPage = Math.max(0, this.totalPages - 1);
            }
            var index = this.currentPage * this.upperLimit;
            return this.movimientos.slice(index, index + this.upperLimit);
        }
    }
```

And here I'm calculating the number of pages

```
computed: {
    totalPages: function() {
         return Math.ceil(this.resultCount / this.itemsPerPage);
    }
},
methods: {
     setPage: function(pageNumber) {
         this.currentPage = pageNumber;
},

<div v-for="pageNumber in totalPages" class="c-paginacao__select">
     <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="setPage(pageNumber)">
        <span class="active">{{pageNumber+1}}</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your `resultCount` calculated correctly? It needs to be derived from your filtered results.

Comment: @DivyanthJayaraj I think so, I declared resultCount: 0, inside my data, pagination works but when i change the limit of items, the totalPages don't execute again